# Why HTML input element gets resized by the browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, input

I'm trying to make a simple search form on my website and I'm using the input HTML element. But it is acting really weird.

It gets resized by the browser no matter which size I specify in the style. In the example below I've got an input element with the width of 180px, but the browser renders it as 147px. :/

Do you know what could be the problem?

Here's a video example and the code below: http://screencast.com/t/WwqAQDmofhf

```
<div id="search" style="background-color:#000; height:100px;">
    <input style="  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
                    border: medium none;
                    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                    color: #666666;
                    float: left;
                    line-height: normal;
                    margin: 6px;
                    padding: 6px 27px 6px 6px;
                    width: 180px;
                    z-index: 40;"
            type="text" name="searchQuery" value="Search friend" onfocus="this.value=''" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup and style included in your answer seems to work fine in a jsfiddle, showing 180px in Layout tab in Firebug and Chrome console. http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/T7J3z/

Comment: Which browser? And do you have a doctype, or are you running in quirks mode?

Comment: It seems it works when i change from `<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`
to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of 'width' depends on the page's box model.  Traditionally width has included paddings and borders, but the standard model now excludes them.

If you do not have a correct doctype in your html, then most browsers would default to traditional box model, and you would be left with a box of 147px.  Adding a doctype would fix it and force other layout to be standard-compliant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><body>
<div id="search" style="background-color:#000; height:100px;">
    <input style="  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
                    border: medium none;
                    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                    color: #666666;
                    float: left;
                    line-height: normal;
                    margin: 6px;
                    padding: 6px 27px 6px 6px;
                    width: 180px;
                    z-index: 40;"
            type="text" name="searchQuery" value="Search friend" onfocus="this.value=''" />
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to do with:

```
padding: 6px 27px 6px 6px;
```

27px of right padding + 6px of left padding + 147px of reported width = 180px

Have you tried it with Javascript turned off in your browser?

Does it happen in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eSrJK/) example?

Comment: I think padding is around the input of 180px? It shouldn't resize the input.